# Two different framed environments: Strange error message

Tags: errors, environments, mdframed, framed

My code includes the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.1pt]{Theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Remarks}[Theorem]{Remarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem} (Name)\newline
Text: Blah Blah
\end{Theorem}

\begin{proof} Proof the statement....
\begin{itemize}
\item Prove of part A
\item Prove of part B
\end{itemize}
\end{proof}

\begin{Remarks}
\begin{itemize}
\item Remark A
\item Remark B
\end{itemize}
\end{Remarks}
\end{document}
```

which works totally fine and produces

[image]

My goal now is to change the style of my ''Remarks'' into the following:

[image]

For this I found in the internet the following part of a code:

```
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[
  style=remark,
  thmbox={style=M,bodystyle=\normalfont,headstyle=\itshape Remark \upshape\theremark},
  name=Remark,
  within=section,
]{remark}
```

But when I add this in my upper code I get the error at the line of \begin{proof} with the message ''too deeply nested''.....What went wrong?

Comment: Your minimal example does not work, in which "Definition" env is not defined.

Comment: Oh srry.... It should work now

Comment: When I add the extra code to your minimal example it runs without problems. Please provide a complete example showing how you combined the two parts of the code that shows the actual problem.